# Generics and abstract class in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a base abstract class:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T : BasePresenter> : Fragment(){

    protected var presenter : T? = null

    abstract fun providePresenter() : T

    abstract fun getLayoutId() : Int

    abstract fun onCreate()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val root = inflater?.inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false)
        presenter = providePresenter()
        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        onCreate()
    }

}
```

My code in JAVA:

```
//JAVA

private ArrayList<BaseFragment> fragments;
```

How can I use it Kotlin? Code bellow not working

```
//Kotlin

val tabs = ArrayList<BaseFragment>() //error: One type argument expected for class BaseFragment<T : BasePresenter> : Fragment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a type for your `T`

```
val tabs = ArrayList<BaseFragment<SomePresenterType>>()
```

Comment: Thx. It should be working but not in my situation. I need: 
`val tabs = ArrayList<BaseFragment<BasePresenter>>()
tabs.add(instanceOf<ProfileFragment>())`
Maybe I'm doing something wrong in my base architecture?

Comment: In kotlin you just use `()` to create instances, so `tabs.add(ProfileFragment())` should work

Comment: @PavliukR You should specify the complete type of `BaseFragment` in your Java code too by the way. It is a raw type in the example you gave. It should give you a compiler warning.

Comment: I know. It's an extension for me:

`inline fun <reified T : Fragment> instanceOf(vararg params: Pair<String, Any>)
        = T::class.java.newInstance().apply {
    arguments = bundleOf(*params)
}`
That's why I use that line of code

Comment: @marstran What do you mean: the complete type of BaseFragment
As I know kotlin do not support raw types.

Comment: @PavliukR I just mean that your Java code should be this: `private ArrayList<BaseFragment<SomePresenterType>> fragments;`. No, Kotlin does not support raw types, but you shouldn't use raw types in Java either.

Comment: @marstran I understand. Thx

Comment: @lukle Ok, I think your answer is right, but it's not working for my case. But thank you